# How do you set sql_mode to non_strict in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, linux

I tried setting my `sql_mode` to non strict by going into my etc/mysql folder and doing `sudo vim my.conf` and entering `sql_mode=""`, and restarting SQL with `sudo service mysql restart`, but it doesn't works. I also tried entering `SET SQL_MODE=""`; in my phpMyAdmin, but it doesn't works either.

For some reason, this line gives me an error:

```
`created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

#1067 - Invalid default value for 'created'
```

I am assuming it's because of the sql_mode, but is it?

I am using mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.52, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with strict mode.

You need a `TIMESTAMP` column to use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. You can't put it on a `DATETIME` column.

Comment: It worked for others who used the sql dump file. Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: @dms Then it might be an issue related to different MySQL versions.